# Saving changes in Virtual Box

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtualbox

I am currently testing out Mac for the first time through VirtualBox on Windows 7. The VM successfully booted and installed, and I made it to the desktop and later shut down. I then rebooted and changed the VM to read from the disk drive which took me directly into the machine rather than having me re-install. However, if I make changes like creating a folder on the desktop and then shut down, it does not save the newly created folder. How can solve this problem?

Comment: Virtual machines don't just randomly delete files, and VirtualBox does nothing of the sort either. Can you clarify in exactly what situation the file you created isn't being "saved"? - it sounds like you're booting from a startup disc in the VM, in which case you're going to be working in swap memory and unless you mount the hard drive and save the work there, it'll be cleared on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual disk may have gotten set to *immutable* or one of the other special access modes. See [the manual here.](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#hdimagewrites)

To check this, open Virtualbox Manager, then select File->Virtual Media Manager. Select the virtual disk of interest, and see what the media manager displays as the *type*. "Normal" is a normal read/write disk;.

If you need to change the disk mode, you'll have to shut down any VM that is using the disk, then release the disk from the VM. After you've released the disk, you can change the disk mode through the media manager and reattach the disk to the VM.